# Quarkus: Qute Template Static Images Source Path

Tags: java, html, image, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

#### I am making a Qute Template and there is a logo image in the header that I need to have loaded.

The path that is being used within the html is this:
`<img style="width: 10cm;" src="logo.png" alt="Logo Flower">`

The image path from the main folder is `resources/META-INF/resources/logo.png`.
[Click here to see the folders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF291.jpg)

When the template is rendered, the image is not loaded and shows an error on the GET request:

###### `GET http://localhost:8080/api/user/logo.png 404 (Not Found)`

Does anyone have an answer on how to put the path of static files correctly in Qute templates?

Comment: Hello, it seems that your path is wrong, static files never will be served from /api/user/filename automatically. So either you've added custom path for static files OR you need to set correct path. Please update your question with more context

Comment: You should put your image in **META-INF/resources/api/user/image.jpg** . Also if **api** is your context path then put your image in **META-INF/resources/user/image.jpg**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your HTTP path is wrong. It should look like this:
`GET http://localhost:8080/logo.png`

Try to inspect (CTRL + I) your page go to sources and try to figure out where is the problem...

Here is example on my project: `META-INF/resources/logo.png`
[resources path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSlST.png)
, and here is my img tag `<img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Logo">`

Comment: The problem was that the image needed to be in the same path within the resources path, for example if I used the image in a template rendered in the path "api/user/test", the image would need to be in "META-INF/resources/api/user/image.jpg.